# JSON To Model Mapping in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, model, mapping

I am trying to map the JSON I received to a model object in Objective-C.Before I always used ObjectMapper when I coded in swift. I can't seem to grasp the steps I need to go through to achieve the same kind of result when I used ObjectMapper.The problem is when using ObjectMapper you write the code where the mapping happens inside the model class such as;

Ex:

```
public struct Item: Mappable{

public var name: String?
public var id: Int?
public var description: String?

public init?(map: Map) {

}

init(){

}

public mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

    name <- map["name"]
    id <- map["id"]
    description <- map["description"]
}
}
```

I understand that I have to write some kind of underlying helper classes to achieve the same kind of functionality but I can't seem to manage because I don't understand the concept at all. I could not find or even if I did,I could not understand how to do it. Please Help.

My model class would look like this in objective-c Im guessing:

```
@interface BBKProductMetaData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong,nonnull, readonly) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong,nonnull, readonly) NSInteger *id;
@property (nonatomic, assign,nonnull, readonly) NSString *description;

@end
```

What am I supposed to do to map my JSON response to this model.

Comment: Actually there are libs for that like `ObjectMapper` in swift. Search on CocoaPods. Example: https://github.com/LoganWright/JSONMapping

Comment: There is an awesome library https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle

Comment: This is going to be a framework so I am obligated not to use libraries. I don't want my framework to depend on external libraries.

Comment: `-(id)initWithJSONDict:(NSDictionary *)dict{ self = [super init]; if (self){_name = dict[@"name"]; _id = [dict[@"id"] integerValue];, _metaDescription = dict[@"description"];}return self;}` is that what you are looking for? Or are you trying to redoyourself the ObjectMapper lib?Also, i'd avoid `NSString *description;` which could create issue with `-description` of NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-c is not much advance as Swift. So you have to remember some things, like

- If you are creating models, that means it must be accessible to other class, so you have to write that all properties and other declaration things which you want to access to other classes should be in **.h** file not in .m file
- In objective-c you have to import all model classes to header, which you want to access.